# QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory when trying to install a program

Tags: qt

I am trying to install [antidote](https://www.antidote.info) for spellchecking my thesis.

I am on debian stretch: 4.9.0-15-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.258-1 (2021-03-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux

I suscribed to free trial, downloaded the archive, extracted it. There is a script: `Installation.bashc` to run to get started.

- When I run it in usermode, the installer ask for my login, then fails because it needs elevated privileges for installation. Fair enoguh
- When I run it using `sudo` this messages pops: `QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'`

Then I've tried to prepend

- `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000` to the script which causes:
  `QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory /run/user/1000, 1000 instead of 0`
- `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0` which causes the program to end with no error message

Changing ownership of the folder `/run/user/1000` to root (I know it is probably a bad idea, it was just a test) has the same result.